# For-loop to create vector of mean differences in t-tests

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

Let's say I have

```
set.seed(1)
e <- data.frame(tti = log2(runif(200)),
                corona = c(rep("Corona", 100), rep("Before", 100)),
                type = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D")))
```

I am comparing mean differences between `tti` (time to treatment initiation on `log2`-scale) before and during COVID-19 for each `e$type` (here `n=4` but many more in my dataset). I want to apply a `for loop` for this repetitive task, but I am quite new to this and frankly stock at the moment.

My current attempt:

```
for(i in unique(e$type)){
 m <- c(
   round(1-2^(unique(t.test(e$tti[e$type == i] ~ e$corona[e$type == i])$estimate[2]) - 
                unique(t.test(e$tti[e$type == i] ~ e$corona[e$type == i])$estimate[1])),
         digits = 3)*100
 )
}
```

However, this attempt only return one value.

**Expected output**:
`m` should be a vector containing the four estimates of mean differences

```
> m
24.7  10.5  1.5  28.7
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
m <- c()
for(i in unique(e$type)){
 m[i] <- c(
   round(1-2^(unique(t.test(e$tti[e$type == i] ~ e$corona[e$type == i])$estimate[2]) - 
                unique(t.test(e$tti[e$type == i] ~ e$corona[e$type == i])$estimate[1])),
         digits = 3)*100
 )
}
```

This initializes m and then fills it during the loop. That should give you all 4 results in one vector.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Your approach returns `D 
28.7`, and not all four values.

Comment: @cmirian sorry, maybe my answer wasn't clear. I edited it, can you try again?